# Projective resolution of a direct limits is a direct limit of projective resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

This is from Cartan-Eilenberg's book "Homological Algebra".

> **Lemma.** If the $R$-module $M$ is a direct limit of of the direct system $(u_{ij}\colon M_i\to M_j)_{i \leq j}$ of $R$-modules together with canonical injections $u_i\colon M_i\to M$, then there exists projective resolutions of $M_i$ for all $i \in I$ such that their direct limit is a projective resolution of $M$.

The proof provided there is quite short and lacks details. The idea is to construct a projective resolution by recursion.

First, let $F_i = R^{M_i}, F = R^M, \pi_i\colon F_i\to M_i$ is a surjective homomorphism which maps $\sum_{m \in M_i} r_me_{i,m}$ to $\sum_{m \in M_i} r_m m$ and $\pi\colon F\to M$ is, similarly, a surjective homomorphism which maps $\sum_{m \in M} r_me_m$ to $\sum_{m \in M} r_mm$. More generally, a free $R$-module functor $F\colon\mathsf{Set}\to R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$, I think, restricts to the free functor $F{\restriction}_{R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}}\colon R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}\to R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ (defined by the universal property of a free object in a category). By abstract nonsense, free functors are left adjoint, hence they preserve colimits. Now $F(N) = R^N$ and $F(\phi\colon N\to P)$ is a unique $R$-module homomorphism $F(\phi)\colon R^N\to R^P$ which maps $\sum_{n \in N} r_n e_n$ to $\sum_{n \in N} r_n e_{\phi(n)}$. In particular, we have $\pi_j\circ F(u_{ij}) = u_{ij}\circ \pi_i$ and $\pi\circ F(u_i) = u_i\circ \pi_i$. Now since $F{\restriction}_{R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}}$ preserves colimits, $R^M$ is a direct limit of the direct system $(F(u_{ij}))_{i \leq j}$ together with canonical injections $F(u_i)$.

Next the authors claim that $\ker(\pi)$ is a direct limits of $\ker(\pi_i)$. Concretely, $v_{ij}\colon \ker(\pi_i)\to \ker(\pi_j)$ and $v_i\colon \ker(\pi_i)\to \ker(\pi)$ are restrictions of $F(u_{ij})$ and $F(u_i)$, respectively, defined by the universal property of a kernel. What I don't see is why $(v_i\colon \ker(\pi_i)\to \ker(\pi))_{i \in I}$ form a direct limit of the direct systyem $(v_{ij}\colon \ker(\pi_i)\to \ker(\pi_j))_{i \leq j}$. Does it have something to do with $(F(u_i))_{i \in I}$ being a direct limit of $(F(u_{ij}))_{i \leq j}$?

Comment: Direct limits commutes with finite limits.

Comment: @FabioLucchini That's true, but $\pi_i$ is not a direct system of which $\pi$ is a limit.

Comment: Be careful : $F_{\restriction R-\mathsf{Mod}}$ is not actually a restriction : it's a composition with the forgetful functor $R-\mathsf{Mod\to Set}$. In particular it's no longer a left adjoint and does not commute with arbitrary colimits. It *does* commute with filtered colimits, because the forgetful functor does so. (By the way, you didn't say who $A_i$ was)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi (1) I had doubts about that as well, but I think it is a left adjoint to the identity functor on $R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ (trivial forgetful functor). It follows from the universal property of the free $R$-module, restricted to $R$-module homomorphisms instead of arbitrary set-functions. Moreover, it can be proved that if a construction satisfies a free object property with respect to a functor (say, the identity functor in our case), then it defines a left adjoint to that functor (this is one of the equivalent definitions of adjunctions).

Comment: @MaximeRamzi So it's not the functor we need to restrict, but the universal property, and the resulting functor would coincide with the restricted functor.

Comment: No, that's still not true. The adjoint to the identity is the identity. In fact, the free $R$-module functor, on $R-\mathsf{Mod}$, does not commute with direct sums : $R[A\oplus B] = R[A\times B]\not\cong R[A]\oplus R[B]$ (the LHS has a basis consisting of $(a,b)$'s, the RHS has a basis consisting of all $a$'s and all $b$'s)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi But then I don't see where is exactly the mistake here. It is true that the universal property of a free object with respect to some functor defines a left adjoint, isn't it?

Comment: As for your second question, $A_i = M_i$ and $A = M$. I will edit.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have the universal property here : any map of $R$-modules $A\to B$ will indeed induce a map $R[A]\to B$, but the converse is not true : some map of $R$-modules $R[A]\to B$ come from set maps $A\to B$ that aren't $R$-module maps

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think I'm missing something about and risking to look stupid, but don't we need just existence and uniqueness of a an $R$-module homomorphism $R[A]\to B$. That said, given a homomorphism $\phi\colon A\to B$, there needs to exist a uniquee homomorphism $\psi\colon R[A]\to B$ such that $\psi\circ \pi_A = \phi$. Existence is clear. Is it uniqueness that doesn't hold? But why?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi By the way, I believe you, I'm just want to see where I made a mistake.

Comment: Right, maybe a clearer way to say what I said : there is no natural map of $R$-modules $A\to R[A]$. If you had that, then indeed existence and uniqueness would be enough, but here that's not the case.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Ha-ha, of course. I feel so stupid now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries - asking the stupid questions is how I make progress !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the point you're missing is the following fact (be careful, though, that it does *not* generalize to arbitrary abelian categories, the ones where it is true are something like Grothendieck categories):

> Let $0\to A_i\to B_i\to C_i\to 0$ be a direct system of short exact sequences of $R$-modules. Then $0\to \mathrm{colim}_i A_i\to \mathrm{colim}_i B_i\to \mathrm{colim}_i C_i \to 0$ is exact.

In particular, here, you have $0\to \ker(\pi_i)\to R[M_i]\to M_i\to 0$ which is a direct system of short exact sequences, so its colimit is also exact.

But $\mathrm{colim}_i M_i = M$ by definition, $\mathrm{colim}_i R[M_i] = R[M]$ because $R[-]$ commutes with *filtered colimits* (again, following the comments : not all colimits, but it is true for filtered ones).

Therefore the colimit short exact sequence is $0\to \mathrm{colim}_i \ker(\pi_i)\to R[M]\to M\to 0$. But the kernel of $R[M]\to M$ is, by definition, $\ker(\pi)$, so $\mathrm{colim}_i \ker(\pi_i) = \ker(\pi)$ (you may check easily that the maps $\ker(\pi_i)\to \ker(\pi)$ are the correct ones)

Comment: Could you, please, give some reference where it is proven that forgetful functor $R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}\to\mathsf{Set}$ preserves filtered colimits?

Comment: It essentially follows from the description of filtered colimits in both categories. In fact, this is true for forgetful functors from any algebraic category (understand : category of models of an algebraic theory) for the same reason. Maybe the easiest way to do that is as follows : pick any filtered system of $R$-modules, $(M_i)$, and let $M$ be their colimits in $\mathsf{Set}$. Define on it an $R$-module structure such that each $M_i\to M$ is an $R$-module map; that's easy and it's easy to see that it's unique - then check that this satisfies the universal property in $R$-modules

Comment: (for this last bit, it's easy again : let $M_i\to N$ be a cocone of $R$-modules, then it's a cocone of sets, so you get a map of sets $M\to N$. Then the description of the $R$-module structure on $M$ makes it easy to see that $M\to N$ is actually a map of $R$-modules)

Comment: If you want an actual reference (rather than an exercise - but you should do it, it's very instructive, and you really understand where the filtered condition comes into play), this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143505/why-do-finite-limits-commute-with-filtered-colimits-in-the-category-of-abelian-g) says it's done in Borceux I, p.80-81

Comment: This answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164340/directed-colimit-in-a-concrete-category) says that MacLane does it as well

Comment: And (but maybe it's too soon for you to understand why) this question/answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391997/sifted-colimits-of-models-of-a-lawvere-theory) explain the general situation

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but, unfortunately, I failed to do the exercise myself and had to peek inside Borceux. Even worse, I couldn't completely understand Borceux's proof and was forced to ask a question. I'm hoping you could have a look :) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3762124/229776