# Can coproduct be constructed as a filtered colimit?

Tags: category-theory

$X_i\in\mathcal{A},i\in I$,where $I$ is an index set.

Let $\Lambda=\{X_i,X\}$ containing all $X_i$,$X=\coprod_{i\in I} X_i$.

Then $\Lambda$ is a directed set,with preoder $id_i:X_i\to X_i,\iota_i:X_i\to \coprod X_i$.

Consider the colimit of the system $\{j\}_{j\in\Lambda}$:

Claim:$\{X=\coprod X_i,\iota_i:X_i\to X,id_X\}$ is the colimit of the system.

Proof:If $M$ commutes with the system with $m_i:X_i\to M,m:\coprod X_i\to M$,then $m$ must be the morphism determined by the universal property of coproduct.

Hence we can define $f:X\to M$ as $m$.By the universal property of coproduct,$f$ is unique.Therefore $X$ is the colimit of the system.

Is the proof above correct?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't let you construct the coproduct unless you already have the coproduct, and it is not what people mean when they say that coproducts are filtered colimits. Typically I assume what is meant is the observation that arbitrary coproducts are filtered limits of *finite* coproducts; that is, you take the directed set to consist of the coproducts over all finite subsets of $I$, ordered by inclusion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks.So if we have a functor that preserves filtered colimit,can we state that it preserves coproduct?Since I found it here that Free-R Module functor commutes  with filtered colimits,but not preserves direct sum.Does this mean that we cannot find a 'naturual way'(maybe without using coproduct in the system) to construct coproduct as a filtered colimit?

Comment: here in the comment and the first answer:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3761216

Comment: No. It means that if a functor preserves *finite coproducts* and filtered colimits, then it preserves coproducts. The free $R$-module functor from $\text{Set}$ to $\text{Mod}(R)$ preserves all colimits.

Comment: Note that a directed limit over a directed poset with a maximum element is always isomorphic to the object indexed by the maximum.